# Batch renaming of files with a modified timestamp on Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, timestamp, rename, batch-processing

As part of a personal project I have generated a large number of frames.

I want to rename around 6000 png image files in terminal so that within the name they have the time that the frame represents.

e.g

Frame_0001.png to Frame_DDMMYY_HHMMSS.png

Frame_0001.png to Frame_201114_134612.png
Frame_0002.png to Frame_201114_134613.png
and so on...

The first frame starts at 13:46:12 on the 20th November 2014. I want the rest of the images to be renamed sequentially so that they are all named after the date and time they represent.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With perl's (p)rename :

```
rename -n "s/\d+/$(date +%d%m%Y_%H%M%S)/" Frame_0001.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your description is that each frame represents one second of a contiguous sequence.

```
start='13:46:12 20 November 2014'
for i in `ls Frame_????.png|sed 's/Frame_\(....\).png/\1/'`
do  time=`date -d "$start - 1 second + $i seconds" +%d%m%y_%H%M%S`
    mv Frame_$i.png Frame_$time.png
done
```